# Docker fialed to install npm on a jenkins image

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I am trying to setup a Dockerfile which installs **jenkins**, **Chrome**, **Nodejs** and **npm** in a docker container.
I took, the basic commands to buid a Dockerfile from [jenkins page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/) and then i added the installation of Chrome and Node to it. So, it looks like below:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-jdk17
USER root

# Update and install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y lsb-release wget gnupg2 apt-transport-https curl

# Add Docker official GPG key
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg

# Set up Docker repository
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
    signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

# Install Docker CLI
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli

# Add Google Chrome repository and install Chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g npm@latest

# Verify Node.js and npm installation
RUN node --version && npm --version

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER jenkins

# Install Jenkins plugins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean docker-workflow"
```

Sadly when i build the dockerfile using command :

```
docker build -t my-jenkins .
```

I get the error:

```
91.92 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
------
Dockerfile:27
--------------------
  26 |     # Install Node.js and npm
  27 | >>> RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
  28 | >>>     apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs && \
  29 | >>>     npm install -g npm@latest
  30 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - &&     apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs &&     npm install -g npm@latest" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

So, apparently the `npm install -g npm@latest` is failing, but i have no idea, why it doesn't work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `npm` while building the image:

```
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm && \
    npm install -g npm@latest
```